# Cookies set by Google Maps Javascript API

Tags: cookies, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps JavaScript API in my website to display maps of various locations.
Based on online info and a couple of relevant posts on SO, the API is not supposed to create any cookies when called.
However, I have noticed that once in a while, just when rendering a map, I get two additional cookies in my browser: 1P_JAR & CONSENT (both from the domain gstatic.com).
Whenever I delete the cookies they won't come back for a while even after numerous renditions of maps.

As a source for the Maps API I am using `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXX`.

It seems then that I am wrong believing that the API would not create any cookies. Could somenone confirm? And most importantly, is there a way to avoid those cookies being created in my website?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will increase your chance to get an appropriate answer. It also helps you solving the question yourself.